# React Native Expo branch.io

Tags: react-native, expo, branch.io

I am trying to integrate branch.io into expo.
I have this code

```js
Branch.subscribe(bundle => {
  if (bundle && bundle.params && !bundle.error) {
    // `bundle.params` contains all the info about the link.
  }
});
```

For some reason `bundle` does not have params.

Comment: can you share some more details like SDK version, link with which you are testing and some Branch SDK logs

Answer (score 0):

may I ask how to you can the Branch link to open your App at the first place? my branch link keep opening Google Play despite my App configured in Branch dashboard already installed on the device.